# What does "echo a&!d" exactly do step by step?

Tags: bash, echo, alias

I tried the following and I got:

```
$ echo a&!d
echo a&disown 
[1] 16089
a
```

Then I tried the following and I got:

```
$ echo a & disown 
[1] 16101
a
```

Can someone please explain to be what exactly happens in these two cases step by step? What is `!d` exactly is it like an alias or what? Who, under what condition expands it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line consists of two commands:

```
echo a &
```

and

```
!d
```

The first one runs `echo a`, and `&` makes it execute in the background, i.e., asynchronously in a subshell.

The second one is a history substitution, which runs the last command that started with `d`. In your case, this seems to be `disown`, but it could be anything.

`disown` removes the current job from the table of active jobs; in this case, "current job" refers to the job last started in the background.

---

When you use history substitution, the shell prints the expansion before actually running the command; that's why you see the line

```
echo a&disown
```

with the expansion of your command.

The next line,

```
[1] 16089
```

is because a process has been started in the background: `[1]` is the job number, and `16089` is the process ID. The line with `a` is simply the output of the `echo a` command.

When you run the command the second time, without history expansion, you get

```
[1] 16101
```

directly, as there was no history expansion to show; the job number is again `1`, and the process ID has changed to `16101`.

Summarizing:

1. `echo a&!d`

   ```
   echo a&disown   # History expansion
   [1] 16089       # Job number and process ID
   a               # Output from echo command
   ```
2. `echo a & disown`

   ```
   [1] 16101       # Job number and process ID
   a               # Output from echo command
   ```

**References**

- [Job control basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics)
- [Event designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators)
- [`disown`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-disown)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. But my question was actually about why `echo a&disown` is being mirrored, why there is a mirroring and why not `echo a&!d` and why exactly there above `[1] 16101`

Comment: @yukashimahuksay You mean why the command is being printed in the first case?

Comment: I accept that I posted my question very improperly. And I also didn't know the history thing. thanks a lot for that!

Comment: I mean the difference between the outputs of the two commands I posted. Why is it exactly. What are the exact events that take place that lead to this difference.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay The shell's history expansion can be unexpected and quite confusing.  If you don't want such strange things happening, you can turn it off with `set +H`.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay the reason `!d` outputs the full command is because your shell want's you to see the particular command in your history you are currently executing `!d` can be anything. `disown` did not output the full command because you are not invoking any form of history substitution with it. If you use any history substitution mechanism in your shell, it will output the entire command ( just for you to see what command will actually run ) then executes the command

Comment: Worth to note that history expansion is by default turned off in non-interactive shells.